# Term for bowling alley machines that fix pins

Tags: vocabulary

What do we call the bowling alley [machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aEra_Hotel_Bahau_-_Bowling_Alley.jpg) that fix the pins after the ball rolls and hopefully strikes them out?

Comment: I could knock down all the pins if they didn't keep setting them back up again ...

Comment: We're really trying to avoid using this site for "single word requests" where a dictionary, thesaurus or reverse-dictionary lookup will suffice. Typing "machine that sets up the bowling pins" into a Google search brings up the answer in the first set of entries. See [Against Single Word Requests](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/against-single-word-requests/1737#1737)

Answer (score 4):

Pin Setter: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinsetter